# How can I to see the value of variable in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/usuario/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userName: user,
    Userpassword: password
    console.log(Userpassword) //-- > BUT THIS DOSEN´ T WORK!
  })
});
```

I can see the value of variable userName for example, the value of `userName`.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting it in the wrong location.

```js
console.log(Userpassword); // this ok

fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/usuario/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userName: user,
    Userpassword: password
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `console` statement outside. Like this:

```
console.log("User: ", user);
console.log("Password: ", password);

fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/usuario/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userName: user,
    Userpassword: password
  })
});
```

And you have to use the actual variable names: "user" and "password", not "userName" or "Userpassword". These are the keys of the object you are sending in the request.